# Como fazer upload/transferência de arquivos com java?

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um programa que controla as informações dos alunos de uma escola.

Uma das funções desse programa é a de arquivar os documentos escaneados dos alunos, porém é justamente nessa parte que estou com dificuldade.

Quero usar um JFileChooser para escolher o arquivo a ser salvo, depois copiar esse arquivo para uma determinada pasta e salvar tanto o nome do arquivo quando o path dele em um DB.

Preciso de um exemplo/apostila sobre o assunto, pois só achei material voltado para aplicações WEB.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Você já pensou em transformar esse arquivo em binário e salvar no BD dessa forma, caso você precise desse arquivo novamente, você tem que criar um método/função que transforme esses binários em arquivo novamente. Assim caso o arquivo seja apagado por alguém, de problema na máquina onde esses arquivos estão salvos você não perde a informação.

Comment: É simples, tente ir por partes, primeiro faça o upload do arquivo e mande o mesmo pra um diretório. Depois pega as informações do arquivo e mais o diretório em que ele foi salvo e salve tudo isso no banco. Na hora de recuperar o arquivo é só ir no diretório e pesquisar o mesmo.

Comment: então, minha dificuldade está justamente na parte de upload, existe alguma biblioteca de funções só pra manipulação de arquivos?

Comment: @VictorPiovani da uma olhada, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `FileUtils` da `apache commons-io`, dai é só você passar o arquivo que tu fez upload e o destino. Exemplo: `FileUtils.copyDirectory(jFileChooser.getSelectedFile(), "C:\\novosArquivos");`